# Communicate between two devices using Apache Thrift

Tags: client, server, thrift

Heads up: I'm a beginner when it comes to web development and networking.

My aim is to create a windows console application which acts as a server on a local network and have any number of clients on the same network using that server.

I've gone with Apache Thrift and have managed to set up the console application as a server and have created a Unity3D project that acts as a client. ([Using this example code](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/csharp))

It works when I run the server and client on the same device.

How can I get it to work when NOT on the same deivce i.e. when I export and build the unity project on an iPhone?

As I understand it I need to specify a target IP address when setting up my clients but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to assign the server a static (private) ip address.
2. replace the 'localhost' in the client side with the private server`s ip.
3. if the server and the clients share the same local network, basically that should be enough.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try that tomorrow. How do I assign a private IP address for the server or can I just use the device's current IP?

Comment: i would not recommend to use the device's current IP if the server assigns himself an ip via DHCP.  the server must have a static ip -  in order to prevent network problems later. you need to configure the server network adapter or configure the router to assign to him (the mac address of the servers network adapter) excluded ip address. note: the ip address must be from the same subnet of the local network...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case, another solution could involve a **communication server** as a third machine.

Especially when more than two clients are to be involved, this latter approach can be very handy: The server not only takes over the part of managing the communication between the various clients, this also enables you to do some more enhanced communication (think multicast, etc), if such is needed. Peer-to-peer quickly becomes a pain with a large number of clients.

The only caveat is the fact, that Thrift does not support push messages, it is always the client that has to start the RPC interaction. So you will need to design your communication scheme around that limitation.

---

<sub>The scenario outlined above may not match the OPs use case. I want to add it for two reasons: (1) for the sake of completeness (2) to the benefit of future readers looking for exactly this.</sub>

Comment: Hi JensG could you possibly go into a bit more detail for how to create a server that accepts multiple client requests? What are the downfalls? How to create an intermediate server/client that manages multiple devices? Thanks.

Comment: The basic idea is to avoid connection between the devices (peers), instead have a third machine (server) to which all devices connect instead. The service API layout of course depends on what you want to do, so there is no general rule. Pros: the devices don't need a static IP (you can't enforce that in most cases anyway), Cons as outlined above, plus a bit more overhead, plus the additional logic on the server side. As I said, may not fit your particular case but there are scenarios where this approach makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. One last question: what would be the issues if I were to have multiple clients making requests from one server, i.e. no third machine?

Comment: You make requests **to** a server. The machine or device **acting as the server** (i.e. receiving requests/calls) can handle as many connections as it can handle - depends whether you use a `TSimpleServer` or a `TThread[ed|pool]Server` or the like. If all available connections are used, the next call will block and eventually run into a timeout.